# Need to print the values of an array that is parallel to one I sorted using bubble sort

Tags: java, bluej

I have a school project where I am supposed to make a car rental application in BlueJ using Java. For one part, I have 2 arrays, one for the price and one for the name of the car. I have to print the **name** of the car in descending order of the **price**. I have managed to sort the price array in descending order using bubble sort but I am not able to figure out how to print the **name** of the car when I sorted the **price** array. Please help.

```
String carModel[] = {"A", "B", "C"}; //Names of cars
int costPerDay[] = {100, 75, 250}; //Rental cost per day
for(int x = 0; x < costPerDay.length-1; x++) { //Sort the Cost Per Day Array in descending order using bubble sort 
    for(int j = x + 1; j < costPerDay.length; j++) {
        if(costPerDay[x] < costPerDay[j]) {
            int t = costPerDay[x];
            costPerDay[x] = costPerDay[j];
            costPerDay[j] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code snippet. I need to print the **names** of the cars in the descending order of their corresponding cost.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Arrays.toString()` ?

Comment: Create one POJO, and an array of that type - then sort that array. Alternatively, every time you swap a `costPerDay` **also** swap `carModel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String carModel[] = {"A", "B", "C"}; //Names of cars
    int costPerDay[] = {100, 75, 250}; //Rental cost per day
    for(int x = 0; x < costPerDay.length-1; x++){ //Sort the Cost Per Day Array in descending order using bubble sort 
    for(int j = x + 1; j < costPerDay.length; j++){
    if(costPerDay[x] < costPerDay[j]){
    int t = costPerDay[x];
    String s = carModel[x];
    costPerDay[x] = costPerDay[j];
    costPerDay[j] = t;
    carModel[x] = carModel[j];
    carModel[j] = s;
    }
    }
    }
for(int x = 0; x < carModel.length; x++){
 System.out.println(carModel[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was breaking my head on such an easy thing! Just one thing in the last part it shouldn't be `carModel.length-1` but `carModel.length` only

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick to do this. Use another array that indicates the order.

```
    String carModel[] = {"A", "B", "C"}; //Names of cars
    int costPerDay[] = {100, 75, 250}; //Rental cost per day
    // Here's the trick - use an order array.
    int order[] = {0,1,2}; 
    for(int x = 0; x < costPerDay.length-1; x++){ //Sort the Cost Per Day Array in descending order using bubble sort 
        for(int j = x + 1; j < costPerDay.length; j++){
            if(costPerDay[order[x]] < costPerDay[order[j]]){
                int t = order[x];
                order[x] = order[j];
                order[j] = t;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now you can print using `carModel[order[i]]` like I have here with `costPerDay[order[x]]`.